# Unset passed by reference, also unsets original value

Tags: php, reference

I want a reference to an array, and then unset the reference to a few elements of the array. For the question, I have simplified the code:

```
echo"1:";
print_r($this->data);
$return =& $this->data;
foreach(range(1,10) AS $key)
{
    unset($return[$key]);
}
echo"2:";
print_r($this->data);
```

$this->data is an array. This code should keep $this->data untouched, but it doesn't. The output is:

```
1:Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
    )

)
2:Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
    )

)
```

Why is by unsetting the reference, the array in $this->data being changed? All other questions at stackoverflow concerning deleting references uses the unset() function, so why is this giving problems?

Thanks.

Comment: "I'm using my left finger to point at something I don't want to throw away. I make my right finger point at the same thing, and throw away that thing."

Comment: Unsetting a reference normally doesn't change the original data, from what I have read everywhere.

Comment: The difference is that you are not actually unsetting the reference. You are unsetting a value within the referenced data. See this sandbox: [PHP Unset Test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3799128b2507b59a2ef9e64bdbeae1e27b8e88ef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that you are not actually unsetting the reference. You are unsetting a value within the referenced data. See this sandbox: [PHP Unset Test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3799128b2507b59a2ef9e64bdbeae1e27b8e88ef)

```
$a=1;
$b = & $a;

unset($a);
echo 'B'."\n";
echo $b;

echo "\n\n";

$c=array(0,1,2,3);
$d = & $c;

unset($c);

echo 'D'."\n";
var_export($d);

echo "\n\n";

$e=array(0,1,2,3);
$f = & $e;

unset($f[2]);
echo 'E'."\n";
var_export($e);
```

Output:

```
B
1

D
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 2,
  3 => 3,
)

E
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 1,
  3 => 3,
)
```

Comment: thanks that must be it. No work-around for this that you know probably?

Comment: There are countless work-arounds, each one comes with a price. What price are you willing to pay? What property of references are you willing to give up in return for being able to delete array elements in the reference without affecting the original array?

Answer (score 1):

By creating a reference using `$return =& $this->data`, you are basically giving the array `$this->data` a new name. That's what references are. Now it does not make any difference whether you access the array using the new name or the old name.

Comment: Yes, but now I want to unset some elements of the reference by using unset(). Using the unset() function on a reference, should not change the original data, but it does in my example.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php "When you unset the reference, you just break the binding between variable name and variable content. This does not mean that variable content will be destroyed" that doesn't happen here when I unset.

Comment: `$this->data` has administrative information like what keys exist in the array, how these keys are ordered, how many elements exist, etc. `$return` is a new name for `$this->data`, it therefore does not create a copy of above mentioned administrative information. It uses the same administrative information. `unset` modifies above mentioned administrative information.